# Visual Studio 2015, ASP.NET 5, Локальный сервер IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2015

Есть проект написанный на ASP.NET 5.
Требуется запуск из Visual Studio 2015 в режиме отладки, но чтоб была возможность подключения к нему по внешнему статическому IP.
Я так понимаю нужно использовать локальный сервер IIS.
Но как это настроить ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Запустить студию с правами администратора
- Открыть свойства веб проекта в студии
- Перейти на закладу Web
- Сменить значение в комбобоксе Servers с IIS Express на Local IIS
- Нажать Create Virtual Directory

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение будет доступно по Project Url, с подстановкой IP или внешнего имени машины вместо localhost.

Запустить отладку можно по <kbd>F5</kbd>, или прицепившись у уже запущенному `w3wp.exe` через `Debug` → `Attach To Process`.

---

Или можно просто вручную создать Application в IIS Manager, зайти на сайт, и точно так же прицепится отладчиком студии.